# grandstack add mutation with relationship

Tags: neo4j, graphql, graphql-mutation, grandstack, neo4j-graphql-js

i'm able to call a mutation in order to insert a node,
but what if i want to insert the relationship with another node as well?

I saw that the grandstack has generated some mutations of this type:  `AddGroupUsers`

How can i call this mutation togeder with the node insert mutation? a sort of transaction? is it possible?
Does it exist a way to define the relationship with the node in the same mutation?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide several operations in Graphql in the following way:

```
mutation($name: String!, $login: String!) {
  CreateRepository(name: $name) {
    name
  }
  AddRepositoryOwner(from: { login: $login }, to: { name: $name }) {
    from {
      login
    }
    to {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Also providing the variables:

```
{
    variables: {
        login: "login",
        name: "name",
    }
}
```

That's the closest to what you want to achieve I am aware of.

Comment: in this way, can i use the returned fields of the first mutation like variables of the second mutations?

Comment: I've never tried, but I don't know any mechanism for that.

Comment: See discussion on related topic here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/583

Comment: `@stellasia`  exactly what i need! thanks.